# spring-boot-starter-quartz cron expression & persistence

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to incorporate quartz into my spring boot project and I have a two issues.
First let me explain what is my end goal here with quartz within my project scope and then I'll present the issues.

My ultimate aim is to set a scheduled function (scheduleCronJob) that every 20-30 seconds checks my custom CronJob table and gets all jobs with their cron expressions - and if they're new or their expression has changed then the change should be propagated onto the quartz tables.

Purpose of the custom CronJob model is to list those cron expression on the GUI so that they can be controlled from there. And once a change is initiated, then the scheduled scheduleCronJob propagates that onto the quartz tables and schedules or reschedules the job(s).

So in short I have my CronJob model with an example:
[image: cron job model with default example]

and here is the code where I tried to implement only one on this one example (RefPoint1):

```
        @Transactional
        @Scheduled(fixedRate = 20000)
        public void scheduleCronJob() throws SchedulerException, ParseException {

            
            //RefPoint1
            String cronExpression = cronRepository.findMatchingCronByItsAliasName("job1").getCronExpression();
            
            //RefPoint2
            //String cronExpression = "54 7 2 1 *";
            
            //RefPoint4
            //String cronExpression = "54 7 2 9 *";
            
            //RefPoint5
            //String cronExpression = "* 7 * 8 * 3 * 9 * 1 * 8";
            
            //System.out.println("Print expr " + cronExpression);
            
            //RefPoint3
            buildExpression(cronExpression);

            scheduler.start();
            
            System.out.println("Scheduler status: " + scheduler.isStarted());

            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(CronQuartzJobClass.class)
                    .withIdentity("cronJob", "group1")
                    .build();
            
            
            
            //RefPoint7
            /*
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("cronTrigger", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(8, 40))
                    .build();
                    */
            
            //RefPoint6
            Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("cronTrigger", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
                    .build();
            
            
            
            // Check if the job exists before scheduling
            if (!scheduler.checkExists(jobDetail.getKey())) {
                scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            }
            
            // Reschedule the job if it already exists
            if (scheduler.checkExists(jobDetail.getKey())) {
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);
            }
            
            System.out.println("Scheduler status: " + scheduler.getJobGroupNames());
            System.out.println("Cron job scheduled.");
        }
```

And I get the following error:

```
    13:21:27.813 [scheduling-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '54 7 2 1 *' is invalid.
    at org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.java:111)
    at my.package.jobs.jobs.CronQuartzService.scheduleCronJob(CronQuartzService.java:126)
    at my.package.jobs.jobs.CronQuartzService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a83b6317.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at my.package.jobs.jobs.CronQuartzService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4c08f9cf.scheduleCronJob(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unexpected end of expression.
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.buildExpression(CronExpression.java:494)
    at org.quartz.CronExpression.<init>(CronExpression.java:276)
    at org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.java:107)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I'm a little bit superstitious so I comment RefPoint1 and uncomment RefPoint2. But still get the same. CronGuru says the expression itself is ok. https://crontab.guru/#54_7_2_1_*

Since I got spring-boot-starter-quarty 2.7.8 in my POM
[image: POM]

I guess its time to delve deeper;

What I did next is I've entered into CronExpression.class and I've basically just copied  buildExpression() function (and all dependent stuff - but won't paste them here for clutter sake for now) into my main class so I can call it and use it inside the scheduleCronJob() and make a test run @RefPoint3.

So this is the function I have (with its variables defined):

```
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 12423409423L;
        
        protected static final int SECOND = 0;
        protected static final int MINUTE = 1;
        protected static final int HOUR = 2;
        protected static final int DAY_OF_MONTH = 3;
        protected static final int MONTH = 4;
        protected static final int DAY_OF_WEEK = 5;
        protected static final int YEAR = 6;
        protected static final int ALL_SPEC_INT = 99; // '*'
        protected static final int NO_SPEC_INT = 98; // '?'
        protected static final Integer ALL_SPEC = ALL_SPEC_INT;
        protected static final Integer NO_SPEC = NO_SPEC_INT;
        
        protected static final Map<String, Integer> monthMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(20);
        protected static final Map<String, Integer> dayMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>(60);
        static {
            monthMap.put("JAN", 0);
            monthMap.put("FEB", 1);
            monthMap.put("MAR", 2);
            monthMap.put("APR", 3);
            monthMap.put("MAY", 4);
            monthMap.put("JUN", 5);
            monthMap.put("JUL", 6);
            monthMap.put("AUG", 7);
            monthMap.put("SEP", 8);
            monthMap.put("OCT", 9);
            monthMap.put("NOV", 10);
            monthMap.put("DEC", 11);
    
            dayMap.put("SUN", 1);
            dayMap.put("MON", 2);
            dayMap.put("TUE", 3);
            dayMap.put("WED", 4);
            dayMap.put("THU", 5);
            dayMap.put("FRI", 6);
            dayMap.put("SAT", 7);
        }
    
        private final String cronExpression = "";
        private TimeZone timeZone = null;
        protected transient TreeSet<Integer> seconds;
        protected transient TreeSet<Integer> minutes;
        protected transient TreeSet<Integer> hours;
        protected transient TreeSet<Integer> daysOfMonth;
        protected transient TreeSet<Integer> months;
        protected transient TreeSet<Integer> daysOfWeek;
        protected transient TreeSet<Integer> years;
    
        protected transient boolean lastdayOfWeek = false;
        protected transient int nthdayOfWeek = 0;
        protected transient boolean lastdayOfMonth = false;
        protected transient boolean nearestWeekday = false;
        protected transient int lastdayOffset = 0;
        protected transient boolean expressionParsed = false;
        
        public static final int MAX_YEAR = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + 100;

    public void buildExpression(String expression) throws ParseException {
        expressionParsed = true;
        
        System.out.println("Expression: " + expression);

        try {

            if (seconds == null) {
                seconds = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }
            if (minutes == null) {
                minutes = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }
            if (hours == null) {
                hours = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }
            if (daysOfMonth == null) {
                daysOfMonth = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }
            if (months == null) {
                months = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }
            if (daysOfWeek == null) {
                daysOfWeek = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }
            if (years == null) {
                years = new TreeSet<Integer>();
            }

            int exprOn = SECOND;

            StringTokenizer exprsTok = new StringTokenizer(expression, " \t",
                    false);
            
            System.out.println("Count token expression: " + exprsTok.countTokens() + " ExprsTok string: " + exprsTok.toString());

            while (exprsTok.hasMoreTokens() && exprOn <= YEAR) {
                System.out.println(" Has more tokens: " +  exprsTok.hasMoreTokens() + " exprOn: " + exprOn);
                
                String expr = exprsTok.nextToken().trim();
                
                System.out.println(" trim " +  exprsTok.nextToken().toString());
                

                // throw an exception if L is used with other days of the month
                if(exprOn == DAY_OF_MONTH && expr.indexOf('L') != -1 && expr.length() > 1 && expr.contains(",")) {
                    throw new ParseException("Support for specifying 'L' and 'LW' with other days of the month is not implemented", -1);
                }
                // throw an exception if L is used with other days of the week
                if(exprOn == DAY_OF_WEEK && expr.indexOf('L') != -1 && expr.length() > 1  && expr.contains(",")) {
                    throw new ParseException("Support for specifying 'L' with other days of the week is not implemented", -1);
                }
                if(exprOn == DAY_OF_WEEK && expr.indexOf('#') != -1 && expr.indexOf('#', expr.indexOf('#') +1) != -1) {
                    throw new ParseException("Support for specifying multiple \"nth\" days is not implemented.", -1);
                }
                
                StringTokenizer vTok = new StringTokenizer(expr, ",");
                while (vTok.hasMoreTokens()) {
                    String v = vTok.nextToken();
                    storeExpressionVals(0, v, exprOn);
                }

                exprOn++;
            }
            
            System.out.println("exprOn " + exprOn + " DAY_OF_WEEK " + DAY_OF_WEEK );

            if (exprOn <= DAY_OF_WEEK) {
                throw new ParseException("Unexpected end of expression.",
                            expression.length());
            }

            if (exprOn <= YEAR) {
                storeExpressionVals(0, "*", YEAR);
            }

            TreeSet<Integer> dow = getSet(DAY_OF_WEEK);
            TreeSet<Integer> dom = getSet(DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Copying the logic from the UnsupportedOperationException below
            boolean dayOfMSpec = !dom.contains(NO_SPEC);
            boolean dayOfWSpec = !dow.contains(NO_SPEC);

            if (!dayOfMSpec || dayOfWSpec) {
                if (!dayOfWSpec || dayOfMSpec) {
                    throw new ParseException(
                            "Support for specifying both a day-of-week AND a day-of-month parameter is not implemented.", 0);
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException pe) {
            throw pe;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ParseException("Illegal cron expression format ("
                    + e.toString() + ")", 0);
        }
    }
```

So when I run RefPoint2 thru the RefPoint3 I got myself a small debug window to check out what is happening since buildExpression() is crucial.
This is what I get printed out:

```
 Expression: 54 7 2 1 *
 Count token expression: 5 ExprsTok string: java.util.StringTokenizer@359b5a19
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 0
 trim 7
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 1
 trim 1
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 2
```

And here I'm not quite sure I understand completely what is happening in the while loop!?
On the first run the next element is trimed, and on the second run also.
So 7 & 1 are out by this given logic. Not sure why is that so?

But anyway, just to confirm it I comment RefPoint2 and uncomment RefPoint4. This is what I get:

```
 Expression: 54 7 2 9 *
 Count token expression: 5 ExprsTok string: java.util.StringTokenizer@7774e25f
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 0
 trim 7
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 1
 trim 9
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 2
```

At this point I'm still not completely sure what is going on inside the while loop so I decide to feed it with RefPoint5 which I uncomment and comment the RefPoint4.
This is what I get:

```
 Expression: * 7 * 8 * 3 * 9 * 1 * 8
 Count token expression: 12 ExprsTok string: java.util.StringTokenizer@3bc2622f
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 0
 trim 7
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 1
 trim 8
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 2
 trim 3
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 3
 trim 9
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 4
 trim 1
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 5
 trim 8
```

And for the first time this condition is fulfilled:

```
        System.out.println("exprOn " + exprOn + " DAY_OF_WEEK " + DAY_OF_WEEK );

        if (exprOn <= DAY_OF_WEEK) {
            throw new ParseException("Unexpected end of expression.",
                        expression.length());
        }
```

Because I get:

```
exprOn 6 DAY_OF_WEEK 5
```

So for the first time, just by feeding more characters in that string expression, I've managed to get buildExpression() to get past that condition if(exprOn <= DAY_OF_WEEK).

Perhaps somebody can shed some light on this? Why does the while loop detract (with .trim) from the expression and then checks that same expression if its <= DAY_OF_WEEK? Because it will certainly be <= than DAY_OF_WEEK.

Anyway, I decide for test sake to just cut the cronExpression out of the game. So I comment RefPoint6 and uncomment RefPoint7 so I can get actually some job inside the quartz table to check if this thing even works.

So everything starts to run and this is console at startup:

```
    14:13:36.327 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
14:13:36.572 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
14:13:38.094 [main] INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
14:13:38.125 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
14:13:38.217 [main] INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
14:13:38.294 [main] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
14:13:38.724 [main] INFO  o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
14:13:38.729 [main] INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
14:13:38.926 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
14:13:38.928 [main] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool - Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
14:13:38.933 [main] INFO  o.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
14:13:38.934 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
14:13:38.935 [main] INFO  org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore - RAMJobStore initialized.
14:13:38.937 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.



14:13:38.937 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
14:13:38.937 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
14:13:38.937 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
14:13:39.054 [main] WARN  o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
14:13:39.245 [main] INFO  s.d.s.w.PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
14:13:39.368 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
14:13:39.370 [main] INFO  o.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl - Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
14:13:39.370 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
14:13:39.392 [main] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
14:13:39.395 [main] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore - JobStoreCMT initialized.
14:13:39.395 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'MYMACHINE'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.



14:13:39.395 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler 'quartzScheduler' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
14:13:39.395 [main] INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory - Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
14:13:39.395 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - JobFactory set to: org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SpringBeanJobFactory@3e2ee637


14:13:39.606 [main] INFO  s.d.s.w.s.ApiListingReferenceScanner - Scanning for api listing references
14:13:39.612 [main] INFO  o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
14:13:39.748 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler quartzScheduler_$_MYMACHINE started.
14:13:39.757 [main] INFO  h.ht.dps.wfm.jobs.Swagger2SpringBoot - Started Swagger2SpringBoot in 5.491 seconds (JVM running for 5.932)
14:13:39.775 [scheduling-1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Scheduler status: true
Scheduler status: [group1]
Cron job scheduled.
14:13:59.770 [scheduling-1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Scheduler status: true
Scheduler status: [group1]
Cron job scheduled.
14:14:19.775 [scheduling-1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Scheduler status: true
Scheduler status: [group1]
Cron job scheduled.
14:14:39.770 [scheduling-1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Scheduler status: true
Scheduler status: [group1]
Cron job scheduled.
```

But I get nothing propagated inside my quartz tables:

[image: quartz tables]

Except here:
[image: quartz-scheduler-state]
in qrtz_scheduler_state table.

One thing that I find weird in console log at startup is that first its not persistent and non-clustered

```
14:13:38.937 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

And then it is persistent and clustered:

```
4:13:39.395 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'quartzScheduler' with instanceId 'WMAK90571701263619369'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.
```

But when the scheduled scheduleCronJob() runs every 20secs then its again non-clustered and obviously non persistent.

```
14:27:59.802 [scheduling-1] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
Scheduler status: true
Scheduler status: [group1]
Cron job scheduled.
```

These are my application properties

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate

spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.clusterCheckinInterval=5000
```

I've set it as jdbc store type; clustered=true and gave it proper delegate class.

So to recap; first issue is that standard cron expression can't get validated thru the CronExpression.class grinder. And second issue is that even when I remove explicit cronExpression feed and try to get it to swallow, like in this example hour & minutes then the job won't get persisted to quartz tables.

What I fail to understand completely is the purpose of the while function there in buildExpression(). In the second issue I've defined the application properties but it seems that somehow palp... :D somehow it reverts back to the default non-persistent non-clustered form.

If anbody has any clues or tips I'd be thankful. Also if you need more data - just shout below, I can provide.

**EDIT 1#**

After user "F. Kadıoğlu" made his comment below, I've tried listening to his advice, this is what I got;
Output:

```
Expression: 0 54 7 2 1 ?
Count token expression: 6 ExprsTok string: java.util.StringTokenizer@2716e79d
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 0
 trim 54
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 1
 trim 2
 Has more tokens: true exprOn: 2
 trim ?
exprOn 3 DAY_OF_WEEK 5
```

Error:

```
[scheduling-1] ERROR o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
java.text.ParseException: Unexpected end of expression.
    at my.package.jobs.jobs.CronQuartzService.buildExpression(CronQuartzService.java:224)
```

The line at which it breaks is the:

```
        if (exprOn <= DAY_OF_WEEK) {
            throw new ParseException("Unexpected end of expression.",
                        expression.length());
        }
```

which is outputed here:

```
exprOn 3 DAY_OF_WEEK 5
```

**EDIT 2#**
Upon further detailed inspection, it appears that there is something *off* with *buildExpression(cronExpression)* function. I've decided to not go with that route since it may be erroneous. Instead within *scheduleCronJob()*, I've tested directly with

```
System.out.println("isValid" + CronExpression.isValidExpression("0 54 7 2 1 ?"));
```

which gives true, and the script runs successfully.

So first part of the issue is resolved, what remains is non persistence and non clustered scheduler.
I've run an scheduler meta print:

```
System.out.println("Print " + scheduler.getMetaData());
```

this is what I got:

```
Print Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler' - running locally.
  Running since: Thu Nov 30 07:45:46 CET 2023
  Not currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.
```

These are my application properties:

```
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate

spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.clusterCheckinInterval=5000
```

Answer (score 0):

your format (`54 7 2 1 *`) is invalid. you can use like this `0 54 7 2 1 ?`

1. cron expression must be 6 or 7(optional) digits
2. Read the first article of the note in the [cron expression](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/crontrigger.html) document carefully.

If you want to use scheduling under spring-context, [You can take a look at my little github project](https://github.com/kadioglumf/requirement-kits/tree/main/scheduler-service)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response; I've updated the original post at the end with what you proposed but still got no further. I'll check out later your github project ;)

Comment: Hi, There may be an error in the method you wrote. I don't get any errors when using the CronExpression class. I expect you to not get any errors when used as `org.quartz.CronExpression c = new CronExpression("0 54 7 2 1 ?");`. Also, when I check if it is valid, it returns true (`CronExpression.isValidExpression("0 54 7 2 1 ?");`).

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I should have gone straight for the clean slate and tested it outright that way! Do you perhaps have an idea what might be an issue with application properties?

Comment: If you extend the QuartzJobBean class and use the executeInternal method in this class, you can use the jobs in the qrtz_job_details table. [this article will probably help you](https://34codefactory.medium.com/spring-boot-quartz-scheduler-example-building-an-email-scheduling-app-code-factory-55579434aae2)